# Angular - TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a json object that i am getting back from an api, here is a sample.

```
{
  "availablePermissions": [
    {
      "id": 25,
      "name": "Dashboard Access",
      "systemName": "DashboardAccess"
    }, {
      "id": 32,
      "name": "Claims Access",
      "systemName": "ClaimsAccess"
    }, {
      "id": 34,
      "name": "Purchasing Reports Access",
      "systemName": "PurchasingReportsAccess"
    }
  ],
  "availableApplicationRoles": [
    {
      "id": "6a8d97b8-7fd5-485c-8eff-5869232b7f26",
      "roleName": "Billing",
      "systemName": null
    }, {
      "id": "fbb6c213-2b19-4eec-891f-0552e3b14b5b",
      "roleName": "Power User",
      "systemName": null
    }
  ],
  "allowed": {
    "dashboardAccess": {
      "144ca9cc-9d56-4cd0-b9b2-c097d606d36e": false,
      "fbb6c213-2b19-4eec-891f-0552e3b14b5b": true
    },
    "claimsAccess": {
        "144ca9cc-9d56-4cd0-b9b2-c097d606d36e": false,
        "fbb6c213-2b19-4eec-891f-0552e3b14b5b": true
    },
    "purchasingReportsAccess": {
      "144ca9cc-9d56-4cd0-b9b2-c097d606d36e": false,
      "fbb6c213-2b19-4eec-891f-0552e3b14b5b": true
    }
  },
  "pager": {
    "pageIndex": 0,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "totalCount": 3,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "hasPreviousPage": false,
    "hasNextPage": false
  },
  "success": true,
  "message": null
}
```

now in my component inside the ngOnInit i have code that will bind it to a property called acl, here is the code.

```
var dummyPermission = {
  id: "0",
  roleName:"Permission",
  systemName:null
}

var self = this;                

this.aclData.loadACL(dataTablesParameters, pageInfo)
  .subscribe(data => {
    if (data.success) {
      self.pluginService.lengthMenuAngularDataTable("#ACLTable", dataTablesParameters.length);
      self.acl = data;
      self.acl.availableApplicationRoles.unshift(dummyPermission);
      callback({
        recordsTotal: self.acl.pager.totalCount,
        recordsFiltered: self.acl.pager.totalCount,
        data: []
      });
      console.log("success load acl table");
      self.pluginService.witzThemeLoader(false);
      self.pluginService.datePicker();
    } else {
      self.pluginService.notificationPopup(null, "danger");
      self.pluginService.witzThemeLoader(false);
      self.pluginService.datePicker();
      console.log("error");
    }
  });
```

now inside my html i try to render them in a table, so here is the code for the row that throws the error.

```
<tr *ngFor="let pr of acl.availablePermissions">
  <td>
    <span>{{pr.name}}</span>
  </td>
  <td *ngFor="let cr of acl.availableApplicationRoles" [hidden]="cr.id == '0'">
    <input 
      attr.data-role-id="{{cr.id}}"
      attr.data-permission-name="{{pr.name}}"
      attr.data-system-name="{{pr.systemName}}"
      [checked]="acl.allowed[pr.systemName][cr.id]"
      class="allow allow_{{cr.id}}"
      type="checkbox" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

now when angular tries to render the page after getting the data, it seems to go into a loop giving the below error every second in the console.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ACLComponent.html:85)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14735)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13849)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
```

now line 85 is the html that i provided above which is this line.

```
 <td *ngFor="let cr of acl.availableApplicationRoles" [hidden]="cr.id == '0'">
```

i just cant figure out what is wrong, i looked in the data they all seem ok, i just have no idea why this is happening, can anyone explain?

#

UPDATE

after some debugging i was able to get to the bottom of the issue, and here it is.

in my api response data object that i have shared, there is an object called "allowed" and here is the format.

```
"allowed": {
"dashboardAccess": {
  "144ca9cc-9d56-4cd0-b9b2-c097d606d36e": false,
  "fbb6c213-2b19-4eec-891f-0552e3b14b5b": true
},
"claimsAccess": {
    "144ca9cc-9d56-4cd0-b9b2-c097d606d36e": false,
    "fbb6c213-2b19-4eec-891f-0552e3b14b5b": true
},
"purchasingReportsAccess": {
  "144ca9cc-9d56-4cd0-b9b2-c097d606d36e": false,
  "fbb6c213-2b19-4eec-891f-0552e3b14b5b": true
}
```

}

now inside the html i have this line.

```
[checked]="acl.allowed[pr.systemName][cr.id]"
```

now this needs to filter from the above allowed object an object that matches the systemName and then filter for an object that matches the id, the problem is, its not an array, so this comes back as undefined.

i am not sure yet how i deal with such a object, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This means that acl.availableApplicationRoles is undefined (the first call of ngFor fails as the first element of the latter cannot be accessed). Are you sure that acl.availableApplicationRoles is being populated?

Comment: is that cr.id string or number ??

Comment: Though it’s not the answer, just a suggestion. Since ES2015 is recommended to use `let` instead of `var` because `let` is considered safer than the latter. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#a-note-about-let

Comment: @Ramana its a string

Comment: @johnmikelridzz i checked in console it has the data, its not undefined

Comment: @SolStein please check my answer - that will fix the issue

Comment: @SmokeyDawson tried that, didnt help

Comment: @SmokeyDawson same error, on the same line

Comment: @SmokeyDawson  i was able to get to the bottom of the issue, and the issue is with the filter, allowed is not an array, its a object, and the object has a list of objects that i am looking to filter, have a look at the allowed object that i shared in the question, and see how i want to get an object with the name matching whats in the foreach, but i get undefined because its not the correct way of doing it, as of now i am not sure how to filter that.

Answer (score 2):

You are hiding the td on cr.id == '0'

```
 <td *ngFor="let cr of acl.availableApplicationRoles" [hidden]="cr.id == '0'">
```

While it does hide but it still create the td element and statement will execute, your are getting error for:

```
 [checked]="acl.allowed[pr?.systemName][cr.id]"
```

because cr.id is 0 in this case:

```
[checked]="acl.allowed[pr?.systemName][0]"
```

you need to add a condition or use *ngIf with container.

Comment: i tried to wrap with *ngIf and still didnt work, same error and it goes to the td, i even took down the hidden attribute and exchanged with a ngIf, didnt work.

Comment: i was able to get to the bottom of the issue, and the issue is with the filter, allowed is not an array, its a object, and the object has a list of objects that i am looking to filter, have a look at the allowed object that i shared in the question, and see how i want to get an object with the name matching whats in the foreach, but i get undefined because its not the correct way of doing it, as of now i am not sure how to filter that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [optional chaining](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/chaining/) and that should fix the issue

```html
<!-- notice the ? after acl and cr -->
<td *ngFor="let cr of acl?.availableApplicationRoles" [hidden]="cr?.id == '0'">
```

Basically what is happening is angular is trying to render your list before your data has been returned so it keeps looping and throwing errors. If you put the `?` after `acl` angular will skip the `*ngFor` until your data has been returned

**EDIT**

You will need to use the `?` on all references to cr like so

```
<tr *ngFor="let pr of acl?.availablePermissions">
  <td>
    <span>{{pr?.name}}</span>
  </td>
  <td *ngFor="let cr of acl?.availableApplicationRoles" [hidden]="cr?.id == '0'">
    <input 
      attr.data-role-id="{{cr?.id}}"
      attr.data-permission-name="{{pr?.name}}"
      attr.data-system-name="{{pr?.systemName}}"
      [checked]="acl.allowed[pr?.systemName][cr.id]"
      class="allow allow_{{cr?.id}}"
      type="checkbox" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: tried it, it didnt help, still in a loop giving errors in the console with the same error on the same line

Comment: did you put the `?` after the cr also? because the error you are getting means that `cr.id` is undefined when you are trying to match it to '0' you should not get this error if you use optional chaining `[hidden]="cr?.id == '0'"`

Comment: yes, here is my line <td *ngFor="let cr of acl?.availableApplicationRoles" [hidden]="cr?.id == '0'">

Comment: Please put the ? on all references to cr and pr as shown in my answer - and please update your question with the exact object you get returned from `console.log(acl.availableApplicationRoles)`

Comment: added, still didnt help, same error. the object is exactly what i get from the api.

Comment: You are definitely missing some crucial information - if the object is as you say and you have put the `?` the above should be working

Comment: Do you get back a json string? or an object? are you converting the json string to a usable object? `JSON.parse(data)`?

Comment: i added logging in the ngOnInit and it logs correctly everything, and i can see its logging in the console before angular renders the page, and the error is happening once the ngOnInit is finish.

Comment: self.acl.availablePermissions.forEach(function (item) {
                                console.log(item.name);
                                self.acl.availableApplicationRoles.forEach(function (cr) {
                                    console.log(cr.id);
                                });
                            });

Comment: i am not using parse, this is the return type

return this.http.get<any>('Permission/Index); and i am just using self.acl = data; from the promis

Answer (score -1):

ok, so i finally i was able to get it work using the following code.

```
<tr *ngFor="let pr of acl.availablePermissions let i = index">
<td scope="col">
    <span>{{pr.name}}</span>
</td>
<td *ngFor="let cb of aclPermissions[i].cb">
    <input attr.data-role-id="{{cb?.roleId}}"
           attr.data-permission-name="{{pr?.permissionName}}"
           attr.data-system-name="{{cb?.systemName}}"
           class="allow allow_{{cb?.roleId}}"
           type="checkbox"
           [checked]="cb?.isChecked" />
</td>
```

as u can see i am using now index, and that helps me loop to the array of objects.

thanks everyone for the help.